# Plot Projects ( PlotProjects ) with React Native module - Not enabling

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get PlotProjects working with the [ReactNative Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotprojects-react-native-module) and I can't seem to get it to load correctly.

I've followed the [docs](http://files.plotprojects.com/documentation/android/3.13.0/how-to-guides/React-Native-integration-guide/) and the [GitHub example](https://github.com/Plotprojects/plot-react-native-module-example) but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Currently I have:

`ios/Supporting Files/plotconfig.json` &
`android/app/src/main/assets/plotconfig.json`

```
{
  "publicToken": "MY TOKEN",
  "enableOnFirstRun": true,
  "maxRegionsMonitored": 20,
  "automaticallyAskLocationPermission": true,
  "automaticallyAskNotificationPermission": true
}
```

`src/utils/plot.js`

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const Plot = NativeModules.PlotProjectsReactModule;

export const initializePlot = async () => {
    try {
        if (!Constants.isDevice) return;

        const { status: locationStatus } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        const { status: notificationStatus } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();

        console.log({ locationStatus, notificationStatus });

        if (locationStatus === 'granted' && notificationStatus === 'granted') {
            console.log('initializing...');
            Plot.initialize();
            console.log('initialized!');
        } else {
            console.log('Location permission denied');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
};

export default Plot;
```

`App.js`

```
import { initializePlot } from './src/utils/plot';
initializePlot();
```

---

I can confirm that `Plot.initialize()` is being called, however, when calling

```
Plot.isEnabled(enabled => console.log({ enabled }));
```

`enabled` is always `false`, even if I wait 30 seconds before calling.

I'd expect to see a new profile appear in my dashboard for the new device once initialized, but get nothing.